# Hyperplane does not pass through the origin.

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer and let $f$ be the function $f(x) = (1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n−1})$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, Show that a hyperplane (of codimension 1) containing the points $f(1),f(2),\dots,f(n)$ does not pass through the origin.

I know what hyperplane and co-dimension are, but I am unable to understand how can it not pass through the origin. Since any subspace always contains the zero vector. Or is it not what passing through the origin means?

By the way this a problem from Berkeley Prelims exam, Spring 22 so it is not an invalid question I think.

Comment: You have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so it can only reasonably mean an affine hyperplane. For example for $n=2$ it is the line through $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$. So actually what they are asking is to show that this hyperplane is NOT a vector subspace.

Comment: It's not the difficulty of the question that makes this a poor question, it's the lack of effort. Where in the question does it say that the function is linear? In fact, it can't be.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Yes I didn't consider what an affine hyperplane is. I will try to solve it now.

Comment: @JohnDouma I think there was no question of the linearity of the function, we have just created $n$ points using some function $f$ like the example in the first comment.

Comment: BTW thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael has said in the first comment here a *hyperplane* means an *affine hyperplane* and we just have to check now whether they are linearly independent or not. In that case we consider the standard basis $\beta=\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $e_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$, the Kronecker delta function.

Now, we consider the matrix $ B = \begin{bmatrix}
f(1)&f(2)&f(3)& \cdots&f(n)
\end{bmatrix}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
[B]_\beta 
&=\begin{bmatrix}
f(1)&f(2)&f(3)& \cdots&f(n)
\end{bmatrix}_\beta\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1& \cdots&1\\
1&2&3&\cdots&n \\
1&2^2&3^2&\cdots&n^2 \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&2^{n-1}&3^{n-1}&\cdots&n^{n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Which is a Vandermonde matrix and has determinant not equal to zero. This completes the proof